# Orthonormal Basis assumption in PCA derivation

Tags: self-learning, linear-algebra

I'm doing the Mathematics for Machine Learning course on Coursera (Course 3, Week 4). I am trying to understand the derivation of PCA.

Specifically from:

$J =\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\Vert \sum_{j=M+1}^{D}(b_j^TX_n)b_j\Vert^2$ to

$J =\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{j=M+1}^{D}(b_j^TX_n)^2$

Why does the trailing $b_j$ disappear?

Apparently it's due to b being a vector in the orthonormal basis. But can anyone help me understand. TIA.

Additional info:

$b$- vectors forming an Orthonormal basis.

$J$- Average reconstruction error.

$X_n$ - A datapoint

[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks for editing, Nitin. Also would appreciate if you kindly define the terms.

Comment: It comes directly from the definition and the fact that $||y||^2 = y^\prime y$ for any column vector $y.$

Comment: @whuber but there is a multiplication by $X_n$ right? And matrix multiplication is not commutative right?